# Android Test Accounts getting Item Unavailable for in-app purchase

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase

I'm having a problem testing an in app purchase on the Test Accounts that I setup in my developer profile.

The application is uploaded as a draft, the in app product is published, and the application is signed.  When I test the in app purchase on my phone (developer account) the item is found and comes up in the Google Play store.  When I try and purchase this from my device I get an error which I'm sure is because you are not allowed to buy your own products.  When I install the app on another device where the primary account is one of my test accounts I get an "Item Unavailable".  I did not do a factory reset as I asked some friends to test.

In my profile I have them listed like person1@gmail.com, person2@gmail.com, person3@gmail.com.

I feel like the problem lies with the Test Accounts because it comes up fine using the developer account, but I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks